# Uipath integration with saucelabs using tunnelName for deviceconnection

Tags: mobile, uipath, saucelabs

We are trying to connect with saucelabs  mobile and uipath mobile device manager.we have a saucelabs tunnel created with our secured network.
In appium capabilities tried giving

TunnelName tunnel1 - not worked

Can any one help Mr know what would be the  correct setting name to send mobile network traffic through tunnel.

I tried tunnelName as capability but device connection not established
Then tried sauceoptions.tunnelName...now deviceconnection is established but want to know if that is the right settings?

Comment: Mr was a typo...apologies

Comment: Is `not worked` part of what you tried, or a characterisation of observed outcome (→ didn't work)? (Please edit `Mr` to whatever is intended.)

Comment: it is resolved now.   capabilities to include  - tunnelName and tunnelOwner

Comment: Your question will be more useful to future readers when there is a useful answer. You are welcome to answer your own questions. (What about the `Mr` typo?)